# Where can I find xxhash64 and md5 collision probability statistics?

Tags: php, hash, memcached, md5

I dont find any info about % of collisions for xxhash64.

I'm going to use it for cache system (to generate hash keys which need to be unique, about a hundreds millions).
Now i use md5, but i don't need cryptographic property.

So i need some info, to decide does is it a good decision for my task.
In best case - comparison of the number of collisions between md5 and xxHash64.

Comment: xxhash64,  fast algoritm ? what is it ? 64 bit hash?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can calculate yourself by using the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

In general the mathematical expression that gives you the probability of hash function is :

> p(k) = 1 - exp(-k(k-1)/2N, k (number of hashes) randomly generated values, where each value is a non-negative integer less than N (number of possible hashes):
>
> N = 2^(number of bit), example for md5 it is 2^128, or 2^32 for 32 bit-hash

**If you use md5**

will produce a 128-bit hash value, by applying this formula you get this 'S' graph. This graph explains, for example, in order to get a collison probability of 50% (0.5), you need at least 21 000 000 trillion of hashes or 21 quintillion of hashes!!!!  If you we use less than, for instance 1 billion of hashes, the probability of collision is negligible.

[image]

*If you are using hundred millions of hashed keys, the probability of collision is 0% using md5.*

**If you use xxhash64,**

**Assuming that xxhash64 produce a 64-bit hash**. You will get this graph.
[image]

According to this picture, you can see that if the collision percentage is 50%, you need at least 5 billion of hashes. Two of the 5 billion of hashes   can have an odd of 1/2 to have the same hashes!!! If you have around 12 billion of hashes there is 100% of chance that the hashes collide.

*If you are using hundred millions of hashed keys, the probability of collision is 0.033% using xxhash64*.

This [link](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138363/why-is-md5-considered-a-vulnerable-algorithm) explains why md5 or fast hash method are not secure.

Comment: Thanks - nice graphs! But it looks like you lost a zero there. Don't you mean  21 quintillion == 21,000,000 trillion hashes for MD5?

Comment: Ya i lost a zero... yes... edited according to your suggestion.